# Plastic junction boxes and covers in floor?

Tags: wiring, junction-box

Our family room is currently being remodeled to include a raised/tray ceiling. Once the drywall was removed from the ceiling and the plywood removed from the attic floor above the family room, it was discovered that a LOT of wiring was going down the center of the room and had to be relocated. The electricians 'relocated' the wiring by adding 20-30 plastic junction boxes in the floor of the attic and covering them with solid, plastic covers. The attic was and will be re-floored with plywood and the space will eventually be used as livable space.

Are plastic junction boxes and plastic box covers appropriate for a floor? If not, what should have been used? Is this method of rewiring (using junction boxes) safe?

Comment: Were the electricians told the attic would be remodeled into habitable space?   Could this be still be done whilst concealing the junction boxxes behind a cabinet door or other tasteful yet finger-removable coverup?

Answer (score 2):

Plastic junction boxes and plastic covers are generally fine for wire connections. However, every junction box must remain accessible. You cannot put a floor over them.

If you were to have the junction boxes mounted *through* the floor, they must be protected, and plastic covers would probably not be considered acceptable in most jurisdictions. Metal covers, or specialty floor boxes and covers might meet code.